# Module wl not found [ubuntu 16.04.1]

Tags: drivers, 16.04, wireless, kernel, broadcom

There is no wireless connectivity in ubuntu 16.04.1 
here is more information
I already tried this one, which suggested downloading the deb file and manually installing the [broadcom-wireless driver](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download) package. [No more wireless after quantal update: 'Module wl not found'](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074847)

Running `sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb` returns:

```
(Reading database ... 181254 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) over (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.17~16.04.1+0.8-0ubuntu2) ..
```

Therefore running `sudo modprobe wl` returns:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic
```

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` returns:

```
13:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 4):

One issue is that you are installing an older version of the package; let's remove it:

```
sudo dpkg -P bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Next, please see:

> Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
>   kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

Please get a temporary internet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic
```

Once the reinstallation of the headers is complete, next do:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Please post any errors or warnings.

Comment: I am not quite sure OP has a Broadcom. Too many people think that "Broadcom" means "wireless".

Comment: LOLOL! Indeed. We will be interested to see his lspci.

Comment: Thanks chilli555. Here is what reinstalling returns-
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.30+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.34.36) ...

Comment: @Pilot6, True true! But I have a broadcom.

Comment: Please run: `cat  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.30+bdcom/build/make.log ` and paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I'll take a shot without even seeing the log! Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Hey! chilli555, I removed and installed it again, the wireless module wasn't found.
I'll try reinstalling the generic headers and dkms modules again try again.

Comment: You're the greatest chili555!!!
Thanks a lot! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know anything about fixing the problem yet and you dont know whats wrong read:  [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) . If the specific obstacle is **WL not found** continue.
This procedure worked for a ***Broadcom*** PCI:ID ***14e4:43b1***. You will need an internet connection (through ethernet cable for instance).

The current general solution is to deactivate/uninstall the *Broadcom* wireless module and rebuild it - because something has gone wrong. There's a huge amount of info on how to do this, and you may have to reboot and other stuff, I wont go into that here, see the above link.

But (if you read the output when rebuilding) you may get the ***WL not found*** error like I did and it just wont work. This was very frustrating after 10 hours of syncopated reboot uninstall install, UEFI secureboot off, proprietary driver click on/off  etc.

Long story short, Type the following to see if you have the headers for your *Linux* distribution:

`ls -l /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

This command `ls` combined with `uname -r` above will list your headers (for the exact version of Ubuntu you have) It wont do anything else. If you don't have the files nothing will be returned (and that's why the ***WL*** component wont build). If that's the case the following may fix your problem - Get the headers by typing:

`sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

now that you have all the pieces (hopefully) you can rebuild the module by typing:

`sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`

OR (if you  have not uninstalled it - reinstall it using):

`sudo apt reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`

If it works you will see the wireless icon in a few seconds.